# Cognos Report Studio 10.2 Crosstab report with Percent difference for total difference

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I am trying to create a Data Item that takes a column for difference between 2 fields that is calculated and has a total at the end of column 3. I want to then create another Data Item that takes each difference and get the percentage from the total of column 3 to get that percentage.

```
    Row    Column1 column2 column3 column4
    XXX        100      90      10  (XXX column3(10) / total(column3(45)))
    YYY         50      35      15  same as above but for YYY
    ZZZ         60      40      20  same as above but for ZZZ
    total    210      165     45  21.42%
```

I cannot get the column4 to calculate correctly. I have changed the aggregate function to "Calculated".

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks Dan

Comment: I have tried this for Column4: column1 - column2 / total(column3). This produces a number but is not correct. I get different percentage than what i would expect. usually higher.

Answer (score 0):

It looks simple. Try

```
column3 / total(column3 for report)
```

Comment: That doesnt work. it might be due to the fact i am using a Cube to get the measure from in the report. supposedly it should work but does not work.

Comment: For cubes you have to use a different aggregation method. Try aggregate([column3] for report) for the divisor.